# No "Metal Compiler" in target's Build Settings

Tags: xcode, metal, build-settings, cikernel

I'm using Xcode 10.1. Even when using the search function in my target's Build Settings, I can't find a "Metal Compiler" or anything related Metal.

Described here, there are Metal settings that can be set in Build Settings, but there's nothing I can find: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-init

Has it been cut out or replaced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must have at least one Metal source file (which usually has a `.metal` extension) in the Compile Sources build phase of your selected target in order for Metal compiler settings to appear.